# Django/Tastypie - DELETE requests deleting everything

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, tastypie

I have the following model

```
class Open(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()
    opened=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and the following resources

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
class OpenResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Open.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'open'
```

I'm trying to delete an Open object from some User's open_set.
For posting, I use the following code (using Requests):

```
content={"name":file_path,
        "user":"/api/v1/user/2/"}
requests.post(
                url='http://localhost:8000/api/v1/open/',
                data=json.dumps(content),
                headers={'content-type':'application/json'},
)
```

which works perfectly and does exactly what I want.
However, when trying to use similar code for deleting:

```
content={"name":file_path,
        "user":"/api/v1/user/2/"}
requests.delete(
                url='http://localhost:8000/api/v1/open/',
                data=json.dumps(content),
                headers={'content-type':'application/json'},
)
```

it just deletes all the Open objects from that user (in this case, user with id=2), instead of deleting only the Open objects whose "name" is file_path and whose "user" is "/api/vi/user/2/"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

### Distinction between list and detail.

The RESTful methods are split into two kinds:

detail (for GET, PUT and DELETE):

```
/api/v1/objects/1/
```

and list (for GET, PUT and DELETE):

```
/api/v1/objects/
```

POST and PATCH are bit different.

Means that `DELETE /api/v1/objects/` will remove all objects.

To delete one object you have to provide path with id:

```
DELETE /api/v1/objects/1/
```

[Link to documentation](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#deleting-data)

### How filtering works in Tastypie:

You cannot just add things to content and wish to be picked up by Tastypie. All not meant to be there information will be ignored by Tastypie.

If you want to filter your list use queryset parameters:

```
/api/v1/objects/?name=asdfasdf&user=2
```

And allow filtering of these:

```
from tastypie.constants import ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
class Open(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()
    opened=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    filtering = {'name': ALL, 'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}
```

After these changes you will be able to delete set of objects:

```
DELETE /api/v1/objects/?name=asdfasdf&user=5
```

[Link to documentation](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering)

### Edit:

So your call will look like this:

```
import urllib
content={"name":file_path,
        "user":"/api/v1/user/2/"} # If doesn't work change '/api/v1/user/2/' into 2 I am not sure about this
url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/open/?' + urllib.urlencode(content)
requests.delete(
                url=url,
                data=None,
                headers={'content-type':'application/json'},
)
```

Comment: Well, I actually have that in my code, eventhough I didn't post it. That's why I can't understand why it's happening

Comment: That urlencode is not suitable for use with tastypie

Comment: Great explanation.....BUT What to do when i just want to delete specific fields data same as patch request updates any field without touching other fields. I am using Tastypie with Mongonengine, so i am having a ListField in my model and i can update the list using patch request but what should i do for deleting any item from the ListField.??? And what to do when there are more than one ListField in my MongoEngine Model class.